# Why do my pages 404 when I rewrite the slug of my custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm working with a wordpress theme I purchased for a glassblowing business and it provides me with a custom post type called "portfolio".

What I'm trying to do is rewrite the slug of that custom post type to match the type of product it is.

If the product were under the "lighting" category, the URL would be domain.com/**lighting**/product-name

If the product were under the "object" category, the URL would be
domain.com/**objects**/product-name

I can get the desired permalink structure for my posts by adding the following code to my child theme's functions.php, but when I do, all of my other pages (minus the home page) return a 404.

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'dynamic_keep_product_slug', 10, 2 );
function dynamic_keep_product_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'portfolio' === $post_type ) {
        $my_args = array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%project-type%', 'with_front' => true ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('category')
        );
        return array_merge( $args, $my_args );
    }

    return $args;
}

function keep_product_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'project-type' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%project-type%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
    } else {
        return str_replace( '%project-type%' , 'products' , $post_link );
    }

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'keep_product_link', 10, 2 );
```

I'm far from an expert, so can someone tell me where I've gone wrong here? Is there a better way of giving this post type multiple slug options?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to (re)save permalinks. After changing stuff like taxonomy and slugs, you get 404 if you don't. Go to the WP dashboard and head to Settings > Permalinks and just hit save.

Also, you can consider another way to do this. Leave the CPT unchanged and create categories for it, lighting, objects, etc. Then remove the CPT slug from the url. It will kepp the CPT category slug and that's what you want. Just note that in this case you can't have any pages or posts whose slugs start with "portfolio", or conflicts would arise. Apart from that it works fine, I've done this with woocommerce, hiding the "product" slug but keeping the categories' slugs

Comment: thanks! worked after save the permalinks settings